# R rowwise calculation with other element of dataframe

Tags: r

I need to perform a calculation on each row of a dataframe, that looks in the same dataframe for another row or a number of other rows that fullfill some criteria related to the original row and then substracts a column from the original row by the searched rows. To be more clear, I have a dataframe with gene expression values (so called Ct values) that need to be normalized to their respective controls (genes which are assumed to be expressed at a constant level), which is done by substracting them from the mean of the controls.
I already achived this, but I want to do it in a more elegant way, without using a loop. Here is my sample code

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

dat <- tibble(Sample.Name=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), 
              gene = c("ref1", "ref1", "ref1", "ref2", "ref2", "ref2", "gene1", "gene1", "gene1"), 
              Ct=c(22.1, 21.8, 21.9, 18.2, 18.5, 18.1, 30.4, 31.2, 33))

refGenes = c("ref1", "ref2")

# calculate Delta ct (Ct-mean(refGenes))
dCT <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  # Iterate over all rows
  row <- dat[i,]
  dat %>%
    # find reference genes that match sample name
    subset(dat$Sample.Name == row$Sample.Name &
             dat$gene %in% refGenes) %$%
    # Calculate mean of corresponding ref genes
    mean(Ct, na.rm = T) %>%
    subtract(row$Ct, .) %>%
    # Add to dCT vector
    rbind(dCT, .) -> dCT
}
dat %<>% cbind(dCT)
#clean up unused objects
rm(i, dCT, row)
```

The data is not necesarrily structured as nice as in this example data and the datasets might be way bigger.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to achive this with a apply function or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Sample.Name) %>%
  mutate(dCT = Ct - mean(Ct[gene %in% refGenes]))

#  Sample.Name gene     Ct   dCT
#  <chr>       <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a           ref1   22.1  1.95
#2 b           ref1   21.8  1.65
#3 c           ref1   21.9  1.90
#4 a           ref2   18.2 -1.95
#5 b           ref2   18.5 -1.65
#6 c           ref2   18.1 -1.90
#7 a           gene1  30.4 10.2 
#8 b           gene1  31.2 11.0 
#9 c           gene1  33   13
```

Comment: Amazing! I was familiar with those functions, but I was thinking way to convoluted. Thank you so much!

Comment: I bought you a coffe on buymeacoffee.com but I pasted a wrong stackoverflow link in the thank you note, so please ignore the link :D